# JQuery multiple :not() selector on href not working

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm trying to trick a script I found on the web with multiple `:not()` selectors. Unfortunately I couldn't find why it is not working...

The purpose of the script is to scroll to anchor when clicked. But I have a responsive menu witch contains a anchored link called `#menu`. So I'm trying to exclude it from the function. Here is my selector:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([href*='menu'])').click(function() { 
      myfuntion 
  });
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the single quotes around `menu` to double quotes

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([href*="menu"])').click(function() { myfuntion });
```

Inside single quotes `'something here'` you can only use double quotes `""` to remain in the `String` context

```
'something "foo" bar'
```

otherwise the parser will expect a string/variable concatenation:

```
'something'+ foo +'bar' // << correct concatenation with foo variable
```

or it will throw

```
'something' foo 'bar'   // << Unexpected identifier / Syntax Error
```

Comment: I feel pretty lame... Thanks <3

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan can you add explanation why it should be `"` and not `'`? just for future reference thank you